# Extract all unique keys from arbitrarily nested json data with jq

Tags: json, parsing, scripting, command-line-interface, jq

As the subject states, my goal is to write an `all_keys` function to extract all keys from an arbitrarily nested json blob, traversing contained arrays and objects as needed, and outputting an array containing the keys, without duplicates.

For instance, given the following input:

```
[
    {"name": "/", "children": [
      {"name": "/bin", "children": [
        {"name": "/bin/ls", "children": []},
        {"name": "/bin/sh", "children": []}]},
      {"name": "/home", "children": [
        {"name": "/home/stephen", "children": [
          {"name": "/home/stephen/jq", "children": []}]}]}]},
    {"name": "/", "children": [
      {"name": "/bin", "children": [
        {"name": "/bin/ls", "children": []},
        {"name": "/bin/sh", "children": []}]},
      {"name": "/home", "children": [
        {"name": "/home/stephen", "children": [
          {"name": "/home/stephen/jq", "children": []}]}]}]}      
]
```

The `all_keys` fuction should produce this output:

```
[
  "children",
  "name"
]
```

To this end, I devised the following function, but it's as slow as it is convoluted, so I was wondering whether you could come up with a more concise and faster way of obtaining the same result.

```
def all_keys: 
    . as $in |
    if type == "object" then 
        reduce keys[] as $k (
            [];
            . + [$k, ($in[$k] | all_keys)[]]
        ) | unique
    elif type == "array" then (
        reduce .[] as $i (
            [];
            . + ($i | all_keys)
        ) | unique
    ) 
    else
        empty
    end
;
```

For reference, running that function on [this 53MB json file](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/benchmarks/files/jeopardy/jeopardy.json) takes roughly 22 seconds on my Intel T9300@2.50GHz CPU (I know, it's quite ancient but still works fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach would just collect all the keys and get the unique values.

```
[.. | objects | keys[]] | unique
```

But with that data, it's a bit on the slow side since the keys need to be collected and sorted.

We could do a little better with this. Since we're trying to determine all the distinct keys, we'd use a hashmap of some sort to be more efficient. Well, we have objects that can act as such.

```
reduce (.. | objects | keys[]) as $k ({}; .[$k] = true) | keys
```

I didn't measure the time on this but it's magnitudes faster than the other version.  I didn't even wait for the other to finish, this one was well within 10 seconds on my work machine (i5-2400@3.1GHz).

Comment: Thanks!

I had totally missed the `..` operator, without it I couldn't imagine anything else but the solution I devised. Your last approach takes about 14 seconds on my machine, whilst the one you labeled _naive_ takes 19 seconds.

Comment: Actually, now I realize I could have used `recurse(.[]?)` instead of `..` anyway. I sensed I was making things more complicated than they should have. :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find the following variant of the OP's all_keys is actually slightly faster than the version using `..`; this is probably to be expected -- for jeopardy.json, `..` generates altogether 1,731,807 JSON entities whereas there are only 216,930 JSON objects:

```
def all_keys:
  def uniquely(f): reduce f as $x ({}; .[$x] = true) | keys;
  def rkeys:
    if type == "object" then keys[] as $k | ($k, (.[$k]|rkeys))
    elif type == "array" then .[]|rkeys
    else empty
    end;
  uniquely(rkeys);
```

Comment: It is indeed faster than @jeff-mercado proposed solution with `jq-1.4-1-e73951f` shipped with Ubuntu 15.10. It's however about as fast as Jeff's version with `jq-1.5rc2-152-g0b82185` I just compiled out of the git repository.

Thank you guys!